# Apache Cascading on Mesos

Tags: cascading, mesos

I am currently learning about Mesos and was wondering if it is possible to execute jobs defined with Cascading on a Mesos pool. Since Mesos supports Hadoop and Cascading flows compile to Hadoop jar files I assume that it is feasible. But do I need respect specific settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do to run Cascading jobs with Hadoop on Mesos. You do, however, need to have Hadoop installed and configured. You'll probably want to use HDFS in addition to an MapReduce implementation.

- For MR1, the project lives here: https://github.com/mesos/hadoop
- For MR2, the project lives here: https://wiki.apache.org/incubator/MyriadProposal

Comment: Spot on! Two additions: Myriad has been accepted as Incubator now, see http://incubator.apache.org/projects/myriad.html and re Hadoop/HDFS see also https://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/run-hadoop-on-mesos/ and https://mesosphere.com/2015/03/20/mesosphere-announces-hdfs-on-mesos/